# Powershell howto Get-Process and write output using switch instead of if statement

Tags: powershell, if-statement, foreach, switch-statement

I have no idea if my switch syntax is even close. I have used the switch using numbers. I would very much appreciate any help. I would like to replace my foreach if statements into a single switch.

```
Set-StrictMode –Version Latest

$services = @( 'DHCP', 'browser', 'TapiSrv', 'lanmanserver', 'spooler', 'lanmanworkstation' )
$serv1 = Get-Service $services

foreach ($service in $services) { 
if ( $serv1.Status -eq 'Running') {  
Write-Host $service is running.
}
}

foreach ($service in $services) {
if ( $serv1.Status -eq 'Stopped') {
Write-Host $service is stopped.
}
}


switch ($serv1.Status) {
Running Write-Host $service is running. | foreach ($service in $services)
Stopped Write-Host $service is stopped. | foreach ($service in $services) 
}
```

Comment: Try typing this in PowerShell: `help about_switch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Switch implementation might look something like this:

```
foreach ($service in Get-Service)
{
 Switch ($service.Status)
  {
    'Running'  { Write-Host "$($Service.name) is running." }
    'Stopped'  { Write-Host "$($Service.name) is stopped." }
     Default   { Write-Warning "$($Service.name) is in an unrecognized state." }
  }
}
```

Since you're only testing for Running or Stopped, I'm assuming that's the only two states you're expecting and any other state would be abnormal.  The Default condition will pick up any services in a state other than Running or Stopped, and generate a warning for those.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think tha you need `switch/case` in you case, what about using `where-object` CmdLet (alias : Where) to filter your list:

```
Get-Service $services |where {$_.Status -eq "running"}
```

you can use it in :

```
write-host "Running services : $(Get-Service $services |where {$_.Status -eq "running"})"
write-host "Stopped services : $(Get-Service $services |where {$_.Status -eq "stopped"})"
```